# Switch Bar в PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt5, toggle, qcheckbox

Как можно реализовать такую кнопку - `Switch` в *PyQt5* как на скриншоте,   при нажатии выполнять определённые действия?

[image: Switch Bar]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class ToggleButton(QCheckBox):
    def __init__(
        self,
        width=70,
        bgColor="#777",
        circleColor="#DDD",
        activeColor="#00BCff",
        animationCurve=QEasingCurve.OutBounce,
    ):
        QCheckBox.__init__(self)
        
        self.setFixedSize(width, 40)
        self.setCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor)

        self._bg_color = bgColor
        self._circle_color = circleColor
        self._active_color = activeColor
        self._circle_position = 3
        self.animation = QPropertyAnimation(self, b"circle_position")

        self.animation.setEasingCurve(animationCurve)
        self.animation.setDuration(500)
        self.stateChanged.connect(self.start_transition)

    @pyqtProperty(int)
    def circle_position(self):
        return self._circle_position

    @circle_position.setter
    def circle_position(self, pos):
        self._circle_position = pos
        self.update()

    def start_transition(self, value):
        self.animation.setStartValue(self.circle_position)
        if value:
            self.animation.setEndValue(self.width() - 35)
        else:
            self.animation.setEndValue(3)
        self.animation.start()

    def hitButton(self, pos: QPoint):
        return self.contentsRect().contains(pos)

    def paintEvent(self, e):
        p = QPainter(self)
        p.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)

        p.setPen(Qt.NoPen)

        rect = QRect(0, 0, self.width(), self.height())

        if not self.isChecked():
            p.setBrush(QColor(self._bg_color))
            p.drawRoundedRect(
                0, 0, 
                rect.width(), 
                self.height(), 
                self.height() / 2, 
                self.height() / 2
            )

            p.setBrush(QColor(self._circle_color))
            p.drawEllipse(self._circle_position, 3, 32, 32)
        else:
            p.setBrush(QColor(self._active_color))
            p.drawRoundedRect(
                0, 0, 
                rect.width(), 
                self.height(), 
                self.height() / 2, 
                self.height() / 2
            )

            p.setBrush(QColor(self._circle_color))
            p.drawEllipse(self._circle_position, 3, 32, 32)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
   def __init__(self):
      super().__init__()

      self.centralwidget = QFrame()
      self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
      
      self.toggleBtn = ToggleButton()
      
      self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
      self.layout.addWidget(self.toggleBtn, Qt.AlignCenter, Qt.AlignCenter)


if __name__ == '__main__':
   app = QApplication(sys.argv)
   w = MainWindow()
   w.resize(500, 500)
   w.setWindowTitle("Анимация кнопки переключения")
   w.show()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если возможно то как менять эту круглую штуку внутри Switch?

Comment: `p.setBrush(QColor(self._circle_color))`; `p.drawEllipse(self._circle_position, 3, 32, 32)`

Comment: Я имел в виду при активации

Comment: @TFader `self.toggleBtn = ToggleButton(circleColor="#f00", activeColor="#00B")`

Comment: А возможно ли прописать ей местоположение? И как при активации её сохранять выбор (то есть если активировал её, при следующем входе будет активна эта кнопка)

Comment: @TFader да, все возможно. Просмотрите примеры как это делается https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A217323+QSettings . Попробуйте что-то сделать и если не будет получаться - зададите новый вопрос и расскажите что вы пытались сделать и что у вас не получилось.

Comment: Классное решение :)

Comment: @S.Nick, кст, заметил что в `paintEvent` дублируется код в условии с `self.isChecked()`, там можно вынести из условия `p.setBrush(QColor(self._active_color if self.isChecked() else self._bg_color))`

Answer (score 4):

[Есть еще реализация,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51825815/5909792) в отличии от реализации [в соседнем ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1355583/201445), сделана от абстрактной кнопки, что правильно

Единственное, в чем была проблема, это ошибка с `setPixelSize` из-за передачи в него `float`, что вызывало ошибку и падение. Исправил так:

```
font.setPixelSize(int(1.5 * self._thumb_radius))
```

**switch_button.py:**

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QPropertyAnimation, QRectF, QSize, Qt, pyqtProperty
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QAbstractButton,
    QApplication,
    QHBoxLayout,
    QSizePolicy,
    QWidget,
)


class Switch(QAbstractButton):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, track_radius=10, thumb_radius=8):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)
        self.setCheckable(True)
        self.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Fixed, QSizePolicy.Fixed)

        self._track_radius = track_radius
        self._thumb_radius = thumb_radius

        self._margin = max(0, self._thumb_radius - self._track_radius)
        self._base_offset = max(self._thumb_radius, self._track_radius)
        self._end_offset = {
            True: lambda: self.width() - self._base_offset,
            False: lambda: self._base_offset,
        }
        self._offset = self._base_offset

        palette = self.palette()
        if self._thumb_radius > self._track_radius:
            self._track_color = {
                True: palette.highlight(),
                False: palette.dark(),
            }
            self._thumb_color = {
                True: palette.highlight(),
                False: palette.light(),
            }
            self._text_color = {
                True: palette.highlightedText().color(),
                False: palette.dark().color(),
            }
            self._thumb_text = {
                True: '',
                False: '',
            }
            self._track_opacity = 0.5
        else:
            self._thumb_color = {
                True: palette.highlightedText(),
                False: palette.light(),
            }
            self._track_color = {
                True: palette.highlight(),
                False: palette.dark(),
            }
            self._text_color = {
                True: palette.highlight().color(),
                False: palette.dark().color(),
            }
            self._thumb_text = {
                True: '✔',
                False: '✕',
            }
            self._track_opacity = 1

    @pyqtProperty(int)
    def offset(self):
        return self._offset

    @offset.setter
    def offset(self, value):
        self._offset = value
        self.update()

    def sizeHint(self):  # pylint: disable=invalid-name
        return QSize(
            4 * self._track_radius + 2 * self._margin,
            2 * self._track_radius + 2 * self._margin,
        )

    def setChecked(self, checked):
        super().setChecked(checked)
        self.offset = self._end_offset[checked]()

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        super().resizeEvent(event)
        self.offset = self._end_offset[self.isChecked()]()

    def paintEvent(self, event):  # pylint: disable=invalid-name, unused-argument
        p = QPainter(self)
        p.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing, True)
        p.setPen(Qt.NoPen)
        track_opacity = self._track_opacity
        thumb_opacity = 1.0
        text_opacity = 1.0
        if self.isEnabled():
            track_brush = self._track_color[self.isChecked()]
            thumb_brush = self._thumb_color[self.isChecked()]
            text_color = self._text_color[self.isChecked()]
        else:
            track_opacity *= 0.8
            track_brush = self.palette().shadow()
            thumb_brush = self.palette().mid()
            text_color = self.palette().shadow().color()

        p.setBrush(track_brush)
        p.setOpacity(track_opacity)
        p.drawRoundedRect(
            self._margin,
            self._margin,
            self.width() - 2 * self._margin,
            self.height() - 2 * self._margin,
            self._track_radius,
            self._track_radius,
        )
        p.setBrush(thumb_brush)
        p.setOpacity(thumb_opacity)
        p.drawEllipse(
            self.offset - self._thumb_radius,
            self._base_offset - self._thumb_radius,
            2 * self._thumb_radius,
            2 * self._thumb_radius,
        )
        p.setPen(text_color)
        p.setOpacity(text_opacity)
        font = p.font()
        font.setPixelSize(int(1.5 * self._thumb_radius))
        p.setFont(font)
        p.drawText(
            QRectF(
                self.offset - self._thumb_radius,
                self._base_offset - self._thumb_radius,
                2 * self._thumb_radius,
                2 * self._thumb_radius,
            ),
            Qt.AlignCenter,
            self._thumb_text[self.isChecked()],
        )

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):  # pylint: disable=invalid-name
        super().mouseReleaseEvent(event)
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            anim = QPropertyAnimation(self, b'offset', self)
            anim.setDuration(120)
            anim.setStartValue(self.offset)
            anim.setEndValue(self._end_offset[self.isChecked()]())
            anim.start()

    def enterEvent(self, event):  # pylint: disable=invalid-name
        self.setCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor)
        super().enterEvent(event)


def main():
    app = QApplication([])

    # Thumb size < track size (Gitlab style)
    s1 = Switch()
    s1.toggled.connect(lambda c: print('toggled', c))
    s1.clicked.connect(lambda c: print('clicked', c))
    s1.pressed.connect(lambda: print('pressed'))
    s1.released.connect(lambda: print('released'))
    s2 = Switch()
    s2.setEnabled(False)

    # Thumb size > track size (Android style)
    s3 = Switch(thumb_radius=11, track_radius=8)
    s4 = Switch(thumb_radius=11, track_radius=8)
    s4.setEnabled(False)

    l = QHBoxLayout()
    l.addWidget(s1)
    l.addWidget(s2)
    l.addWidget(s3)
    l.addWidget(s4)
    w = QWidget()
    w.setLayout(l)
    w.show()

    app.exec()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Накидал пример:](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/tree/257e798e760459a620d6ce70ecfb3240fccc0d6c/qt__pyqt__pyside__pyqode/SwitchButton__example/from_QAbstractButton)

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QLabel
from switch_button import Switch


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        switch_btn1 = Switch()
        label_switch_btn1 = QLabel(f'Checked: {switch_btn1.isChecked()}')
        switch_btn1.clicked.connect(lambda checked: label_switch_btn1.setText(
            f'Checked: {switch_btn1.isChecked()}'
        ))

        switch_btn2 = Switch()
        label_switch_btn2 = QLabel(f'Checked: {switch_btn2.isChecked()}')
        switch_btn2.clicked.connect(lambda checked: label_switch_btn2.setText(
            f'Checked: {switch_btn2.isChecked()}'
        ))

        main_layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        main_layout.addWidget(switch_btn1)
        main_layout.addWidget(label_switch_btn1)

        main_layout.addWidget(switch_btn2)
        main_layout.addWidget(label_switch_btn2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()

    app.exec()
```

Скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А как в этом случае менять цвет _track_radius? Пробовал что-то вроде этого ```self._track_color = {
                True: palette.setColor(QPalette.Switch, QColor(201, 176, 46)),
                False: palette.dark(),
            }```, но вылезают разного рода ошибки.

Comment: @PandaStock, те методы `palette` типа `dark()` возвращают `QBrush`, а у вас будет None, т.к. это вернет setColor: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpalette.html#setColor . Т.е. нужно положить `QBrush`. А если посмотреть как код работает с данными `self._track_color` и его аналогами, то увидите, что их значения попадают в `setBrush` из `QPainter`, а у того в `PyQt5` такие варианты типов в параметре: `def setBrush(self, brush: QBrush | QColor | GlobalColor | QGradient)`, а значит можно не только `QBrush`

Comment: @PandaStock, поэтому взял в качестве примера ваш цвет `QColor(201, 176, 46)` и заменил им `palette.highlight()`, и все работает https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PH5e.png . С вас плюсы за мои старания ;) :D

Comment: Я доволен! :) Надеюсь когда нибудь достигну такого уровня кунг-фу.

Comment: @PandaStock, пожалуйста :)

Answer (score 1):

Такое есть в `QML`: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-switch.html#details, но если чисто на виджетах, то в коробке такого нет, нужно вручную делать

Нашел [тут реализацию](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51023362/5909792) и кое-что в нее [добавил](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/53730a8e996ef3dd342868ffef939d3952351fc8/qt__pyqt__pyside__pyqode/SwitchButton__example/from_QWidget/switch_button.py#L14):

- Методы: `isChecked`, `valueText`
- Сигнал: `clicked`

**switch_button.py:**

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui


class SwitchButton(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    clicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal(bool)

    def __init__(self, parent=None, w1="Yes", l1=12, w2="No", l2=33, width=60):
        super(SwitchButton, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        self.__labeloff = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.__labeloff.setText(w2)
        self.__labeloff.setStyleSheet("""color: rgb(120, 120, 120); font-weight: bold;""")
        self.__background  = Background(self)
        self.__labelon = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.__labelon.setText(w1)
        self.__labelon.setStyleSheet("""color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-weight: bold;""")
        self.__circle      = Circle(self)
        self.__circlemove  = None
        self.__ellipsemove = None
        self.__enabled     = True
        self.__duration    = 100
        self.__value       = False
        self.setFixedSize(width, 24)

        self.__background.resize(20, 20)
        self.__background.move(2, 2)
        self.__circle.move(2, 2)
        self.__labelon.move(l1, 5)
        self.__labeloff.move(l2, 5)

    def isChecked(self) -> bool:
        return self.__value

    def valueText(self) -> str:
        return self.__labelon.text() if self.isChecked() else self.__labeloff.text()

    def setDuration(self, time):
        self.__duration = time

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if not self.__enabled:
            return

        self.__circlemove = QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self.__circle, b"pos")
        self.__circlemove.setDuration(self.__duration)

        self.__ellipsemove = QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self.__background, b"size")
        self.__ellipsemove.setDuration(self.__duration)

        xs = 2
        y  = 2
        xf = self.width()-22
        hback = 20
        isize = QtCore.QSize(hback, hback)
        bsize = QtCore.QSize(self.width()-4, hback)
        if self.__value:
            xf = 2
            xs = self.width()-22
            bsize = QtCore.QSize(hback, hback)
            isize = QtCore.QSize(self.width()-4, hback)

        self.__circlemove.setStartValue(QtCore.QPoint(xs, y))
        self.__circlemove.setEndValue(QtCore.QPoint(xf, y))

        self.__ellipsemove.setStartValue(isize)
        self.__ellipsemove.setEndValue(bsize)

        self.__circlemove.start()
        self.__ellipsemove.start()
        self.__value = not self.__value

        self.clicked.emit(self.isChecked())

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        s = self.size()
        qp = QtGui.QPainter()
        qp.begin(self)
        qp.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing, True)
        pen = QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.NoPen)
        qp.setPen(pen)
        qp.setBrush(QtGui.QColor(120, 120, 120))
        qp.drawRoundedRect(0, 0, s.width(), s.height(), 12, 12)
        lg = QtGui.QLinearGradient(35, 30, 35, 0)
        lg.setColorAt(0, QtGui.QColor(210, 210, 210, 255))
        lg.setColorAt(0.25, QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255, 255))
        lg.setColorAt(0.82, QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255, 255))
        lg.setColorAt(1, QtGui.QColor(210, 210, 210, 255))
        qp.setBrush(lg)
        qp.drawRoundedRect(1, 1, s.width()-2, s.height()-2, 10, 10)

        qp.setBrush(QtGui.QColor(210, 210, 210))
        qp.drawRoundedRect(2, 2, s.width() - 4, s.height() - 4, 10, 10)

        if self.__enabled:
            lg = QtGui.QLinearGradient(50, 30, 35, 0)
            lg.setColorAt(0, QtGui.QColor(230, 230, 230, 255))
            lg.setColorAt(0.25, QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255, 255))
            lg.setColorAt(0.82, QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255, 255))
            lg.setColorAt(1, QtGui.QColor(230, 230, 230, 255))
            qp.setBrush(lg)
            qp.drawRoundedRect(3, 3, s.width() - 6, s.height() - 6, 7, 7)
        else:
            lg = QtGui.QLinearGradient(50, 30, 35, 0)
            lg.setColorAt(0, QtGui.QColor(200, 200, 200, 255))
            lg.setColorAt(0.25, QtGui.QColor(230, 230, 230, 255))
            lg.setColorAt(0.82, QtGui.QColor(230, 230, 230, 255))
            lg.setColorAt(1, QtGui.QColor(200, 200, 200, 255))
            qp.setBrush(lg)
            qp.drawRoundedRect(3, 3, s.width() - 6, s.height() - 6, 7, 7)
        qp.end()


class Circle(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Circle, self).__init__(parent)
        self.__enabled = True
        self.setFixedSize(20, 20)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        s = self.size()
        qp = QtGui.QPainter()
        qp.begin(self)
        qp.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing, True)
        qp.setPen(QtCore.Qt.NoPen)
        qp.setBrush(QtGui.QColor(120, 120, 120))
        qp.drawEllipse(0, 0, 20, 20)
        rg = QtGui.QRadialGradient(int(self.width() / 2), int(self.height() / 2), 12)
        rg.setColorAt(0, QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        rg.setColorAt(0.6, QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        rg.setColorAt(1, QtGui.QColor(205, 205, 205))
        qp.setBrush(QtGui.QBrush(rg))
        qp.drawEllipse(1,1, 18, 18)

        qp.setBrush(QtGui.QColor(210, 210, 210))
        qp.drawEllipse(2, 2, 16, 16)

        if self.__enabled:
            lg = QtGui.QLinearGradient(3, 18,20, 4)
            lg.setColorAt(0, QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255, 255))
            lg.setColorAt(0.55, QtGui.QColor(230, 230, 230, 255))
            lg.setColorAt(0.72, QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255, 255))
            lg.setColorAt(1, QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255, 255))
            qp.setBrush(lg)
            qp.drawEllipse(3,3, 14, 14)
        else:
            lg = QtGui.QLinearGradient(3, 18, 20, 4)
            lg.setColorAt(0, QtGui.QColor(230, 230, 230))
            lg.setColorAt(0.55, QtGui.QColor(210, 210, 210))
            lg.setColorAt(0.72, QtGui.QColor(230, 230, 230))
            lg.setColorAt(1, QtGui.QColor(230, 230, 230))
            qp.setBrush(lg)
            qp.drawEllipse(3, 3, 14, 14)
        qp.end()


class Background(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Background, self).__init__(parent)
        self.__enabled = True
        self.setFixedHeight(20)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        s = self.size()
        qp = QtGui.QPainter()
        qp.begin(self)
        qp.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing, True)
        pen = QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.NoPen)
        qp.setPen(pen)
        qp.setBrush(QtGui.QColor(154,205,50))
        if self.__enabled:
            qp.setBrush(QtGui.QColor(154, 190, 50))
            qp.drawRoundedRect(0, 0, s.width(), s.height(), 10, 10)

            lg = QtGui.QLinearGradient(0, 25, 70, 0)
            lg.setColorAt(0, QtGui.QColor(154, 184, 50))
            lg.setColorAt(0.35, QtGui.QColor(154, 210, 50))
            lg.setColorAt(0.85, QtGui.QColor(154, 184, 50))
            qp.setBrush(lg)
            qp.drawRoundedRect(1, 1, s.width() - 2, s.height() - 2, 8, 8)
        else:
            qp.setBrush(QtGui.QColor(150, 150, 150))
            qp.drawRoundedRect(0, 0, s.width(), s.height(), 10, 10)

            lg = QtGui.QLinearGradient(5, 25, 60, 0)
            lg.setColorAt(0, QtGui.QColor(190, 190, 190))
            lg.setColorAt(0.35, QtGui.QColor(230, 230, 230))
            lg.setColorAt(0.85, QtGui.QColor(190, 190, 190))
            qp.setBrush(lg)
            qp.drawRoundedRect(1, 1, s.width() - 2, s.height() - 2, 8, 8)
        qp.end()
```

[Использование:](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/tree/53730a8e996ef3dd342868ffef939d3952351fc8/qt__pyqt__pyside__pyqode/SwitchButton__example/from_QWidget)

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QLabel
from switch_button import SwitchButton


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        switch_btn1 = SwitchButton(self, "On", 15, "Off", 31, width=60)
        label_switch_btn1 = QLabel(f'Checked: {switch_btn1.isChecked()}, text: {switch_btn1.valueText()}')
        switch_btn1.clicked.connect(lambda checked: label_switch_btn1.setText(
            f'Checked: {switch_btn1.isChecked()}, text: {switch_btn1.valueText()}'
        ))

        switch_btn2 = SwitchButton(self, "Вкл", 15, "Откл", 31, width=120)
        label_switch_btn2 = QLabel(f'Checked: {switch_btn2.isChecked()}, text: {switch_btn2.valueText()}')
        switch_btn2.clicked.connect(lambda checked: label_switch_btn2.setText(
            f'Checked: {switch_btn2.isChecked()}, text: {switch_btn2.valueText()}'
        ))

        main_layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        main_layout.addWidget(switch_btn1)
        main_layout.addWidget(label_switch_btn1)

        main_layout.addWidget(switch_btn2)
        main_layout.addWidget(label_switch_btn2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()

    app.exec()
```

Скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]